# Unknown: failed to open stream (Jino.ru)

Tags: php, потоки-данных

Сегодня упали все сайты на хостинге Джино (даже сам сайт хостинга). Хостинг поднялся, а сайты так все и лежат с ошибкой:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Нет такого файла или каталога in Unknown on line 0 
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/tmp/sess_99754106633f94d350db34d548d6091a' (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend-5.6/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Кто-нибудь знает как пофиксить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сталкивался сегодня с такой же проблемой. Решил удалением файла `.htaccess` в корне аккаунта (лежит на уровне с папкой с domains).

Не знаю, с чем это связано, по-видимому, накосячили сисадмины компании при обновлении чего-то :)